# Magento product not saving

Tags: magento, save, product

I have come across very different kind of problem. Suddenly in Magento products uploaded not updating anymore.

In detail, when we open products to update and click save button, nothing happens. It started happening suddenly, everything was working fine before.

Please help, its a big problem. I dont know what to do and which files to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where it was gone wrong.

in **js/prototype/validation.js**

This file used by admin product option validation, which I have changed and didn't realize to check for admin validations.

Small change like this solved the problem.

```
if(!admin){
  // put your code for front-end validation
}
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

May be you missed some mandatory field to fill. Check every tab if you have any error asking to fill the fields.

Or, there will be some javascript errors. Check if any JS errors are there, and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I came here after having the same problem. "Save" suddenly stopped working on the product page. The only thing I had done was update prototype.js from 1.7 to 1.7.1 to support fade() in IE10 b/c I have a custom fade on thumbnails.

Well prototype.js 1.7.1 responds with TypeError: value.gsub is not a function when you click save.

Had to revert back because I dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

if magento is configured to work with elasticsearch and elasticsearch is unreachable it also results in this error